# New user is unable to Rdp.

Tags: rdp

When trying to use RDP to access a Linux VM a new user is unable to connect.  It seems to authenticate the same as I do, but then the screen is simply blank.  Do we need to do something else to his account on the VM to allow RDP?  Add him to the group that was created perhaps?

I am able to connect fine, and I tried using the new user credentials and get the same results so it is not system related.

I am using Ubuntu 16
Xrdp
And xfce
This machine is on Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need indeed to use xrdp in order to perform a remote session to your ubuntu machine.  This will ensure that nobody can see your actions on the monitor connected to the machine you are connected to

About the connection issue you have, you could try one of the following options (please test it beforehand and see what's could be working for you)

**Option 1 : You perform a standard installation of xrdp package from ubuntu repository**

You can follow this guide and see if it works for you (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8952).  In a nutshell, you type the following command in a terminal session

*step 1 - Install xrd package* 
 - sudo apt-get install xrdp

*Step 2 - install your xfce desktop interface if not done yet* 
 - sudo apt-get update
 - sudo apt-get install xfce4
*Step 3 - Say to xrdp software to use xfce session*

- echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession

Try to connect but remember that the default keyboard layout for the login page of xrdp is en-us by default (you can change that - please read the guide http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=8952)

Note : because the package is pretty old (0.6.x), you will have basic functionalities

**Option 2 : You perform a custom install of xrdp package and you can use Unity interface**

Visit this page (http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=11719) and download the script provided.  This will perform a custom installation of the xrdp packages (version 0.9.x)

You simply need to execute the script and it will perform the installation. Then, ensure that you logoff from the physical machine and try to perform a remote desktop session.  At the xrdp login screen, provide your credentials and check if this work

Hope this help 
Till next time 
See ya

Comment: Hi Griffon, I can login to the xfce session xrdp is installed. But this user has issues.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering...really really busy..... have you checked that the .xsession file for the user is configured accordingly i.e. add the line    echo xfce4-session >~/.xsession.... Hope this help... till next time see ya